# how to view records in a database for just a particular user with a specific condition in php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a website for my final year school project (a hospital management system using php and mysqli) and I am trying to create a search option whereby a patient can input his/her patient id and view all the details relating to him/her (time to meet with the doctor, date, doctors name etc.)

**Code:**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ghospital");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "something is wrong with the database" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

if (isset($_POST['patient_see_appointment'])) {
  $patient_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['patient_id']);

  $sel_user = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE patient_id = '$patient_id'";

  $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $patient_id = $row['patient_id'];
    $patient_name = $row['patient_name'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $doctor = $row['doctor'];
    $nurse = $row['nurse'];
    $time = $row['time'];
    $am_pm = $row['am_pm'];
    $day = $row['day'];
    $month = $row['month'];
    $year = $row['year'];
  }
  ?>
  <div id="" class="view_emergency"  style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;" >Patients Report Reports</h3>
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>patients id</th>
                <th>patients name</th>
                <th>phone no</th>
                <th>Doctor </th>
                <th>Nurse</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $patient_id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $patient_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $phone; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $doctor; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $nurse; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $day; ?>:<?php echo $month; ?>:<?php echo $year; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $time; ?>:-<?php echo $am_pm; ?></td>
                <td><a href="action.php?delete=1&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?> && " class="btn btn-danger">Print</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php }?>
```

but it is just displaying just one single row where the patient id exist but the patients id exists more than one times in the database and it is suppose to display every single row where the patient id exists.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because you directly insert unsanitised user input into your query. use parameterised queries and prepared statements to better protect your data from hackers. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for an explanation of the problem and also some examples of how to do it safely using PHP/mysqli

Comment: Basically it isn't displaying multiple records because the relevent parts of your HTML aren't inside the `while` loop. It'll just use whatever the last record was to be returned, because you don't try and use the variables till after the loop ends. You need to use the `while` loop to generate the table rows.

Comment: You may fail this assignment based on the fact that your code is vulnerable to attack. Avoid mysqli_* like the plague and use PDO.

Comment: @ProEvilz: I doubt it, comp sci lecturers tend to be around ~15 years behind best practices `;-)`. But yes, some param binding would be good.

Comment: Godwin, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ADyson, please i dont know how to go about what you said please can u help me with the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate and print the query result. 
Please try with this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ghospital");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "something is wrong with the database" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

if (isset($_POST['patient_see_appointment'])) {
  $patient_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['patient_id']);

  $sel_user = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE patient_id = '$patient_id'";

  $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);


  ?>
  <div id="" class="view_emergency"  style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;" >Patients Report Reports</h3>
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>patients id</th>
                <th>patients name</th>
                <th>phone no</th>
                <th>Doctor </th>
                <th>Nurse</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php 
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $patient_id = $row['patient_id'];
                $patient_name = $row['patient_name'];
                $phone = $row['phone'];
                $doctor = $row['doctor'];
                $nurse = $row['nurse'];
                $time = $row['time'];
                $am_pm = $row['am_pm'];
                $day = $row['day'];
                $month = $row['month'];
                $year = $row['year'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $patient_id; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $patient_name; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $phone; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $doctor; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $nurse; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $day; ?>:<?php echo $month; ?>:<?php echo $year; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $time; ?>:-<?php echo $am_pm; ?></td>
                  <td><a href="action.php?delete=1&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?> && " class="btn btn-danger">Print</a></td>
                </tr>

                <?php } ?>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Put `<tr></tr>` inside `while` loop.

**2)** Use [**mysqli_prepare**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#example-1888): A prepared statement is a feature used to execute the same (or similar) SQL statements repeatedly with high efficiency. Prepared statements are very useful against SQL injections, because parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different protocol, need not be correctly escaped. If the original statement template is not derived from external input, SQL injection cannot occur.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ghospital");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "something is wrong with the database" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

if (isset($_POST['patient_see_appointment'])) {

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE patient_id = ?");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST['patient_id']);
  $run_user = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  ?>
  <div id="" class="view_emergency"  style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;" >Patients Report Reports</h3>
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>patients id</th>
                <th>patients name</th>
                <th>phone no</th>
                <th>Doctor </th>
                <th>Nurse</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php while ($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){ $id = $row['id'];?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['patient_id']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['patient_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['doctor']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['nurse']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['day']." : ".$row['month']." : ".$row['year']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['time'].":-".$row['am_pm']; ?></td>
                  <td><a href="action.php?delete=1&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?> && " class="btn btn-danger">Print</a></td>
                </tr>
              <?php }?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php }?>
```

***Quick Links:***

1. [Prepared Statements and Bound Parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)
2. [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#example-1888)

Comment: Thanks Everyone i really appreaciate your help...with you guys i would have been stuck love you all............

Comment: @Godwin: *Glad to help you.* If it helped, then please mark this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find this solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all the PHP at the top. Loop through, and concatenate to an `$output` string.

```
 $output = '';
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $patient_id = $row['patient_id'];
    $patient_name = $row['patient_name'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $doctor = $row['doctor'];
    $nurse = $row['nurse'];
    $time = $row['time'];
    $am_pm = $row['am_pm'];
    $day = $row['day'];
    $month = $row['month'];
    $year = $row['year'];
    $output .= "<tr>
                <td>$id</td>
                <td>$patient_id</td>
                <td>$patient_name</td>
                <td>$phone</td>
                <td>$doctor</td>
                <td>$nurse</td>
                <td>$day:$month:$year</td>
                <td>$time:-$am_pm</td>
                <td><a href=\"action.php?delete=1&id=$id\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Print</a></td>
              </tr>";
  }
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<tbody><?= $output; ?></tbody>
```